# Is CustomPane Folium Map class useable?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, folium

I'm following the examples (jupyter notebooks) on Folium's [github repository](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium) and can't find why class CustomPane is not working.

This is the code in the cell that's not working:

```
m = folium.Map([43, -100], zoom_start=4, tiles="stamentonerbackground", attr="My attr")

folium.GeoJson(geo_json_data).add_to(m)

folium.map.CustomPane("labels").add_to(m)

# Final layer associated to custom pane via the appropriate kwarg
folium.TileLayer("stamentonerlabels", pane="labels").add_to(m)

m.save(os.path.join('results', 'CustomPanes_1.html'))

m
```

**Running the code results in the following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3 folium.GeoJson(geo_json_data).add_to(m)
      4 
----> 5 folium.map.CustomPane("labels").add_to(m)
      6 
      7 # Final layer associated to custom pane via the appropriate kwarg

AttributeError: module 'folium.map' has no attribute 'CustomPane'
```

Any help to clarify what's the problem?

Folium version 0.5.0
Python 3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Leaflet CustomPane class wass added in Folium 0.9.0 and the error I was experimenting was obviously due to the use of Folium 0.5.0.

Installed Folium current version (0.11.0) and works fine.